# Is it reasonable to mention being shortlisted for a prize in CV?

Tags: awards

[The Open Mind Prize](http://openmind.tcs.uj.edu.pl/rules.php), and presumably many other prizes in mathematics and different fields, makes the list of a few (in this case: three) nominees public before the prize is awarded. Suppose that a person was among the shortlist of nominees but was not awarded the prize. Is it reasonable to mention this on their CV? On one hand, being on the shortlist is presumably a form of recognition. On the other hand, being nominated but not winning may be seen as negative.

Comment: At what career stage are you? What other accomplishments do you have? Just to get some context...

Comment: There is a difference between nominated, and shortlisted.
Where not all nominees get shortlisted.
Being shortlisted is the most common name I've seen for this.
Consider saying shortlisted rather than nominated in the title.

Comment: Being nominated for an Oscar is an achievement worth listing. Is your award of relatively comparative prestige in the field? It sounds like it's rather competitive. On the other hand, in case of an internal department/faculty award, with 5 candidates total, it would be silly to mention it in a CV. In case you actually win such a _local_ award, it's worth considering, as it shows that you are recognized at your work place, and are not there just because there were no other candidates for the position. But it's impossible to say without more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fine to list your presence on the shortlist, since that list was published by the awarding group. I would say otherwise if there was no clearly public record and the finalists were merely privately notified.

But the group itself has seen to honor a few candidates separately from all nominees and you can make a note of that.

Not essential, but reinforcing, is the fact that the three "finalists" are asked to present a special lecture at the conference. Congratulations.